# D3: Stacked Bar Chart not parsing data correctly

Tags: d3.js

Trying to create a stacked bar chart and I'm having trouble understanding how to parse and correctly bind the JSON data.

Getting errors of NaN when trying to draw the  parts of the chart.

`Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute height="NaN"`

I'm not very experienced in pulling data from an JS object, or using D3, and putting it in a properly organized array, so that may be where my problem is.

I'm currently using some dummy data to get it working, but ultimately I need a chart that can take an unknown amount of data and stack each 'product', organized by date. I also, was having issues understanding if I should be using d3.net() and using either d.product_name or d.date as my key.

Full fiddle, JS is in Coffeescript
http://jsfiddle.net/toombsday/2hebo511/

```
window.barGraph = ->  
  dataset = [
    {
      "date": "2014-08",
      "amount": 216, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 1'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-08",
      "amount": 116, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 2'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-09",
      "amount": 206, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 1'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-09",
      "amount": 186, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 2'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-10",
      "amount": 216, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 1'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-10",
      "amount": 116, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 2'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-11",
      "amount": 216, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 1'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-11",
      "amount": 206, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 2'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-12",
      "amount": 176, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 1'
    },
    {
      "date": "2014-12",
      "amount": 216, 
      "product_name": 'Annuity 2'
    }
  ]


  margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 30}
  width = 540 - margin.left - margin.right
  height = 320 - margin.top - margin.bottom

  barGraph = d3.select('.reloaded-chart')
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

  stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values((d) -> d.values)
    .x((d) -> d.date)
    .y((d) -> d.amount)

  nest = d3.nest()
    .key((d) -> return d.product_name)

  nested  = nest.entries(dataset)
  layers = stack(nested)

  x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1)
    .domain(dataset.map( (d) -> d.date))

  y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, (d) -> +d.y0 + +d.y)])

  xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')

  yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient('left')
    .ticks(10)

  barGraph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis)

  barGraph.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')

  barGraph.selectAll('.bar')
    .data(layers)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', (d) -> x(d.x))
    .attr('y', (d) -> y(d.y0) - y(d.y))
    .attr('height', (d) -> height - y(d.y))
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())

$ ->
  barGraph()
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have created the stack bar chart based on your dataset.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUcWmuqV5RfuW4g3XF3K?p=preview)

```
var nest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.date; })
.entries(data);
```

Too many places need to be modified, you can check it out yourself.
Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the response. Plunker is currently down so I'm not able to checkout all your changes at this time.

Comment: It seems plnkr lost yesterdays plunks, and they are trying to bring them back, please be patient :-D https://twitter.com/plnkrco/status/542887452676198400

Comment: plnkr is back up. thanks for the taking the time fix my code.  however, I am looking to make a barchart that can handle an unknown amount of products. So there could be one, there could be five. This is what was causing most of my initial confusion.

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208, what you need to do is to change your dataset structure to like its structure.